# SharePoint 2013 on premise and Visual studio online integration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have a SharePoint 2013 enterprise farm and we use Visual studio online to create work items. I have a requirement to create list based workflow and when it completes I need to add a work item to Visual studio online.

Is it possible to integrate SP 2013 with VS Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio Online's REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview) allows you to [create Work Items](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items#Createaworkitem).

In your Sharepoint workflow, you can leverage the [HttpSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn532193.aspx#sec2) activity to make calls to the REST API and create work items as needed.

Comment: Thanks urig. Could you show some example?